# Parsing the input in a AWS Lambda handleRequest into a POJO

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa Skill and I have some problems in the Lambda (written in Java) when parsing the input event.

My Lamba class is like this

```
public class AWSLambdaLaunch implements RequestHandler<RequestEnvelope, ResponseEnvelope>{

  @Override
  public ResponseEnvelope handleRequest(RequestEnvelope requestEnvelope, Context context) {
    //...
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.amazon.ask.model.RequestEnvelope]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@543c6f6d; line: 1, column: 2]

No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.amazon.ask.model.RequestEnvelope]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@543c6f6d; line: 1, column: 2]
```

So I think the problem is there is no way to parse the input object into the RequestEnvelope Object from com.amazon.ask.model.RequestEnvelope.

I have also try the com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.HandlerInput with the same result.

If I change the

```
public class AWSLambdaLaunch implements RequestHandler<RequestEnvelope, ResponseEnvelope>
```

declaration with this one

```
public class AWSLambdaLaunch implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, ResponseEnvelope>
```

I get no errors and it works OK, but I find it more "dirty" to retrieve the elements and values from nested HashMaps

So I am wondering if there is a way to parse the input into a POJO directly or there is an already builded POJO which I can use.

[edit] Here is the code for the [RequestEnvelope](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-java/blob/master/ask-sdk-model/src/com/amazon/ask/model/RequestEnvelope.java) class, from the java aws sdk. As @apandey846 has noted, there is no default constructor in the class, so maybe that is the problem. Is there any way I can use it?

[edit] I have already check that Fully qualified class name for the handler is correctly configured in the Lambda configuration tab as stated here [alexa-java-sdk-issue-102](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/issues/102). I think [issue-104](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/issues/104) is about another issue but referenced just because of the template.

Comment: Can you post the code for `RequestEnvelope`?

Comment: Just check your `RequestEnvelope class` if it has missing default constructor, than add one and try if your error goes away.

Comment: @usuario, did you check similar [alexa-java-sdk-issue-102](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/issues/102) and [issue-104](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/issues/104) seems like setup issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all my fault. I have been mixing up documentation so I was trying the wrong method. I have followed only [this](https://alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and now I can have an Amazon POJO initialized.

To sum up, I was using a lambda handlerequest instead of a skill handle. com.amazon.ask.dispatcher.request.handler.HandlerInput